# Create Thumbnails from a folder of images using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, image-processing, thumbnails

I have a folder of jpegs, and a MySQL database that I hope to use to manage them. The database has one table: 'images', and 7 fields: 'imgID', 'imgTitle', 'imgURL', 'imgDate', 'imgClass', 'imgFamily', & 'imgGender'. The primary key is 'imgID' and the Index Key is 'imgDate'.

What I would like to do is create a PHP file that will go through my folder of images (all jpegs), and create thumbnails of them, which can then be used when displaying links to the images on my webpage. As I will be adding more images to the folder in the future, it would be good to prevent the code from creating doubles of images it has already created thumbnails of.

All literature I have come across recommends using the gd images library to do this, but I'm open to suggestions.

As I'm new to both MySQL and PHP, I was hoping someone could help me with the code. Everything I have tried has failed.

the directory where the images are located is new_arrivals_img/ relative to the site root, and the thumbnails should be placed in new_arrivals_img/thumbnails/ also relative to the site root.

Right now I'm building the site, and thus using MAMP to host it locally. I have had some problem figuring out relative paths for my images. Is there a way to set new_arrivals_img/ as the root?

Comment: Use `convert` on the command line (part of Imagemagik) which can do bulk conversions for you. Far easier to do it this way than try to hack together a script: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php

Comment: Two questions. I wonder about how the php will know which thumbnail belongs to which image when creating links on my page. Would this solution have a condition for that? Or would that be done in the php file that will load the images on the website? Second, what happens when I add more images to the folder? Will it create duplicate thumbnails?

Comment: Use subdirectories. `1.jpg` original images goes into `thumbs/1.jpg`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Supposedly ImageMagick is better on memory but I always have GD at my disposal and it has always done the job for me. Make sure you allocate enough memory in your php.ini

Then use a script like this:

```
<?php
function createThumbs( $pathToImages, $pathToThumbs, $thumbWidth ) 
{
  // open the directory
  $dir = opendir( $pathToImages );

  // loop through it, looking for any/all JPG files:
  while (false !== ($fname = readdir( $dir ))) {
    // parse path for the extension
    $info = pathinfo($pathToImages . $fname);
    // continue only if this is a JPEG image
    if ( strtolower($info['extension']) == 'jpg' ) 
    {
      echo "Creating thumbnail for {$fname} <br />";

      // load image and get image size
      $img = imagecreatefromjpeg( "{$pathToImages}{$fname}" );
      $width = imagesx( $img );
      $height = imagesy( $img );

      // calculate thumbnail size
      $new_width = $thumbWidth;
      $new_height = floor( $height * ( $thumbWidth / $width ) );

      // create a new temporary image
      $tmp_img = imagecreatetruecolor( $new_width, $new_height );

      // copy and resize old image into new image 
      imagecopyresized( $tmp_img, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height );

      // save thumbnail into a file
      imagejpeg( $tmp_img, "{$pathToThumbs}{$fname}" );
    }
  }
  // close the directory
  closedir( $dir );
}
// call createThumb function and pass to it as parameters the path 
// to the directory that contains images, the path to the directory
// in which thumbnails will be placed and the thumbnail's width. 
// We are assuming that the path will be a relative path working 
// both in the filesystem, and through the web for links
createThumbs("new_arrivals_img/","new_arrivals_img/thumbnails/",100);
?>
```

http://www.webcheatsheet.com/php/create_thumbnail_images.php

Comment: how do i go about allocating memory in the php.ini? does this change in the case of using MAMP as it's a localhost? Lastly, will this code allow some sort of connection between the thumbnail and the image to use when creating the links dynamically?

Comment: the php.ini file in MAMP is in (i think) Applications/MAMP/conf/php5/ I have MAMP, not MAMP PRO so you'll have to check the manual if you use PRO. Find `memory_limit` in your php.ini file and change it to something like 64M and restart MAMP. Also, this does a proportional resize based on your desired width (100px in the example call)

Comment: Hey, it worked! Now, one thing... the quality is really not very good. And I'm starting to think it might be a better idea to create the thumbnails with photoshop or something of the like. Eventually I would like to display the thumbnails as links to the larger image using php to create the page. Is there any benefit to using the above script over photoshop for this? Or does it have more to do with the file names being the same? I appreciate your help.

Comment: change this line `imagejpeg( $tmp_img, "{$pathToThumbs}{$fname}" );` to `imagejpeg( $tmp_img, "{$pathToThumbs}{$fname}", 100 );` to improve the quality.

Comment: For batch image processing on the mac, I'm quite a big fan of http://www.lemkesoft.com/content/188/graphicconverter.html if you want to take a different approach. This code is good if you already have the files on a web server which may not have may apps or if you want to automatically create thumbnails in your php app (using just the GD code)

Comment: Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 18432 bytes) in create_thumbs.php on line 36 /// I have ~6MB photos

Comment: "Make sure you allocate enough memory in your php.ini"

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use gd at all, i would use imagemagick. The thumbnails will look much better.

Comment: really? it makes that much of a difference?

Comment: let me ask you this then. is using php to create the thumbnails a good way to go? will it allow them files to be used as links to the larger images? otherwise i could just create the thumbnails in photoshop.